Material UI DataGrid adding a Title
I'm trying to add a general title for a Material UI Datagrid Table, but am having trouble figuring it out. I'm assuming there's a way using the slots={{toolbar}} feature, but can't quite find what I'm looking for.
Here's what I'm working on, quickly edited to show what I'd like:
screenshot of datagrid example with highlighting to show desired outcome
I've tried a few different things similar to this post:
MUI XGrid Disabling Export button from GridToolBar
As well, I've tried creating a custom toolbar component along these lines:
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#toolbar
But nothing has gotten me what I want. Anyone have any answers?

Here is the working implementation using slots prop.
First, create a custom toolbar component:
import { GridToolbarContainer } from '@mui/x-data-grid'

const CustomGridToolbar = () => {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <h1>My Title</h1>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  )
}

export default CustomGridToolbar

✅ USAGE:
<DataGrid
  slots={{ toolbar: CustomGridToolbar }}
 //...other props
/>

